# Install alongside Windows: no drive choice

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 22.04, windows

I am trying to install desktop version of Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS from Live USB for dual-boot. I have the following drives:

1. SSD 1: system drive with Win11.
2. SSD 2: has a partition for Win11 programs, and has 60 GB unpartitioned space, intended for Ubuntu system.
3. HDD: completely empty and not partitioned, intended as a file dump.

My intention is to install Ubuntu into the 60 GB free unpartitioned space on SSD 2.

**The problem**

The Ubuntu installer has an option to "install alongside Windows bootmanager". But when I tick it, it doesn't allow me to choose where to install Ubuntu next. Instead, it only gives me "install now" button, and when I press it, it automatically forces Ubuntu installatiion on HDD without asking.

**Expected Behaviour**

As per Ubuntu's official installation manual, there should be a screen allowing me to choose where to install Ubuntu. Like this (The screeenshot on Ubuntu site is for 23.4, but I guess 22.4 should be the same in this regard?)

[image]
Drive choice from Ubuntu official installation manual

**The question**

What should I do to choose where to install Ubuntu on my PC? Preferrably without manually creating partitions. I didn't download the "most user-friendly distro" to tinker with my drives and possibly screw everything up. I simply want this shiny screen which I referred to earlier.

Comment: You've tagged 22.04 but gave no clues as to which Ubuntu product you're actually asking about (thus which installer you've attempting to use; which is decided at download time with select of product/ISO).  The screen you show is for 23.04 which offers 2 ISO options for Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop & 1 for Ubuntu 23.04 Server; but you're not using 23.04 so have different choices (`subiquity` or `ubiquity`, no `ubuntu-desktop-installer` option exists for 22.04.3). Which are you attempting to use?  (Desktop? Server?)  Clarify your tagging of 22.04 & picture of 23.04? and which product? (Server? Desktop?)

Comment: @guiverc clarified my post. I downloaded  ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso from Ubuntu site.

Comment: The default Ubuntu 22.04 LTS desktop ISO includes the `ubiquity` installer where as the default ISO download for Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop is `ubuntu-desktop-installer` thus of course it differs on screen; if a Ubuntu 23.04 user downloads the *legacy* ISO they'll see what you see, but the 23.04 manual does not cover the *legacy* installer/ISO.  Ubuntu has various manuals, for both Server, Desktop as well as various releases; most can be chosen by altering the URL you were looking at (*alas you didn't provide URL for manual picture*)

Comment: Check you have *fastboot/hibernate* disabled, the installer can ignore partition/drives which are in an *unclean* state (which both *fastboot* and *hibernate* cause).

Comment: @guiverc just tried to install desktop 23.10, it still didn't allow me to change drive. Fastboot and hibernate are both disabled.